# NSUserDefaults error?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsuserdefaults

I am using NSUserDefaults to save my score, but when I kill my app (in the multitasking) and reopen the NSUserDefaults doesn't save the score. Here is all the code involved in NSUserDefaults:

> scores = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
>
> [scores setInteger: currentHighScore forKey:@"currentHighScore"];
>
> -(void) checkHighScore {
>
> ```
> int checkHighScore = [scores integerForKey:@"currentHighScore"];
>
> if(finalScore >= checkHighScore){
>     currentHighScore = finalScore;
>     [scores setInteger: currentHighScore forKey: @"currentHighScore"];
> }
> ```
>
> }

Then I call the check high score in my update method for the death screen. Am I using this wrong or is this a glitch?

Thank You!

Comment: How are you "killing" your app?  IF you're doing it by clicking the stop button in Xcode, that's basically an abort, and the user defaults are not updated.  If you do it by command-Q or quit from the menu it should update.

Comment: Im killing it by closing the app. Multitasking is crashing it. And it is also unplugged from the computer.

Comment: That sounds like 2 different things -- either you're closing it yourself, or it's crashing, which is it?  Are you running this on a device, not the simulator?

Comment: Use [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"currentHighScore"];  may be it'll help

Comment: check it on iPhone device instead of simulator. Mine issue will get solved on device for a BOOL value.

Comment: Do you have scores, currentHighScore and finalScore as global variables? can you tell in which method the first two lines have been called for setting 'currentHighScore' in userdefaults? If these are global and you call first two lines in viewDidLoad method then it is actually setting 'currentHighScore' as a new instance which is initialised as '0'. Please reply so that one can help you.

Comment: I do not think that currentHighScore and finalScore are global variables. If that is needed how do I do that? Also I do not assign currentHighScore any value.

Answer (score 2):

here for save this in last of save data in NSUserDefaults just write this line

```
scores = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[scores setInteger: currentHighScore forKey:@"currentHighScore"];
[scores synchronize]; /// just add this line
```

i hope this help you
:)

Comment: No that didn't work, another other fixes or ways to save the score?

Comment: hi now just click this link and get every information about UserDefaults actually if you use my above code then its work perfect but just see this link you got your answer from that Mate :)